# SDL: How to flush the "Surface Buffer"

Tags: sdl

I want to draw a surface and then pause my program for 1 second. Unfortunately the surface is not drawn onto the screen until after the delay. When does SDL actually draw onto the screen? How can I force it to draw all the surfaces "in the queue" right now?

Here is some skeleton code to illustrate the problem

```
     SDL_BlitSurface(NewSurface, NULL,Display, &destRect); //Draw the new surface
     SDL_Flip(display); //I have tried flipping all the surfaces
     SDL_Delay(1000); //Or Sleep(1000) neither work
     ... //Surface is drawn sometime later but I cannot figure out when.
```

Comment: Calling SDL_Flip() will display the video surface immediately.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment, can you think of any reason why SDL_Flip might not work? The surface shows up later so I think that it has blitted correctly.

Comment: @Beetroot try using debugger and step line-by-line, until you see screen update. But it would be SDL_Flip on screen surface, unless you're hiding some important details. As I recall, SDL have only three functions that *could* update screen - `SDL_Flip`, `SDL_UpdateRect` and `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers` - which is not appears to be your case.

Comment: Check return value of every sdl function.

Comment: Does the time you sleep affect when the image is shown at all?